# Any counter example for this :${\alpha}^2 +{\beta}^2+{\sigma}^2+ x²+y²+z²=9$ . then $xyz\alpha\beta\sigma \geq -2 $?

Tags: number-theory, inequality

I would like to know if there is any counter example for this claim and if that is true how do i can show it ?

**Claim**:

let $\alpha ,\beta,\sigma ,x,y,z$ are real numbers such that :$\alpha +\beta+\sigma+ x+y+z=3$ and  ${\alpha}^2 +{\beta}^2+{\sigma}^2+ x²+y²+z²=9$ .
then $xyz\alpha\beta\sigma \geq -2 $

**Note:** I have used this idea :$(U+V)²\geq 0$  where $U= \alpha+\beta+\sigma $ and $V=x+y+z$ but i got complicated form as shown here in [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(a%2Bb%2Bc%2Bx%2Bz%2By)%C2%B2+%5Cgeq+0)

Thank you for any help !!

Comment: Using Lagrange multipliers, it seems to follow that, at each critical point, either something is $0$ or at most two distinct values are taken by the six coordinates. I didn't take it further, but it seems straightforward.

Comment: A more informative title would help gaining attention of people interested in the subject...

Comment: Ok  thanks for that i will edit the title right now

Comment: Accidentally, the claim is true.

Answer (score 2):

You take a 5-dimensional sphere $\sum_{i=1}^6 x_i^2=9$ and cut it by the plane $\sum_{i=1}^6 x_i=3$. You want to find the minimal value of $\prod_i x_i$ on the resulting 4-sphere. This happens only when the hypersurface $\prod x_i=m$ touches the 4-sphere, which, due to symmetry and convexity, may happen only if all positive coordinates are equal and all negative coordinates are equal. Now it remains to check when it happens and see that the best case is when there is only one negative coordinate (equal to $-2$) and five positive ones (equal to $1$).